# The this keyword in the code reference to in the jquery plugin below?

Tags: jquery

I found this code on the web and was wondering what each "this" keyword reference to? This code has 7 reference to "this" keyword and wondering what each one of them reference to.. I'm assuming it reference to some DOM element but can't make the connection in mind how this is done...

```
(function($) {

   $.watermark = function(element, options) {
      // what does this keyword reference to
      this.options = {};

      // what does this keyword reference to
      element.data('watermark', this);

      // what does this keyword reference to
      this.init = function(element, options) {         

      // what does this keyword reference to
         this.options = $.extend({}, $.watermark.defaultOptions, options); 

         //Manipulate element here ...       
      };

      //Public function
      // what does this keyword reference to

      this.greet = function(name) {
         console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', welcome to Script Junkies!');
      };

      // what does this keyword reference to
      this.init(element, options);
   };

   $.fn.watermark = function(options) { //Using only one method off of $.fn  
      return this.each(function() {
         (new $.watermark($(this), options));              
      });        
   };

   $.watermark.defaultOptions = {
      class: 'watermark',
      text: 'Enter Text Here'
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this = watermark object.

Comment: You must also understand `this` can be set if you invoke the function via `call()` (Function.prototype.call())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have labeled them inline, below:

```
(function($) {

   $.watermark = function(element, options) {
      // referencing the caller of plugin (which is acting like an object)
      this.options = {}; //  this.options is a property

      element.data('watermark', this); //referencing the caller of the plugin

      // referencing the caller plugin and init() is a function of the "object"  
      this.init = function(element, options) {  


      // referencing the caller of the plugin again, and it's options property
      this.options = $.extend({}, $.watermark.defaultOptions, options); 

         //Manipulate element here ...       
      };

      //Public function
      //referencing the caller plugin again, which is an object
      this.greet = function(name) {
         console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', welcome to Script Junkies!');
      };

      // referencing the caller of the plugin again 
      this.init(element, options); //calling the init function of the object
   };

   $.fn.watermark = function(options) { //Using only one method off of $.fn  
      //referencing the caller of the plugin again
      return this.each(function() {
         // representing the current element in the iteration
         (new $.watermark($(this), options));              
      });        
   };

   $.watermark.defaultOptions = {
      class: 'watermark',
      text: 'Enter Text Here'
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `element.data('watermark', this);` : this is not referencing the element... If that's not what you meant, it is a little bit unclear here

Comment: You're right, @Karl-AndréGagnon. That was a mistake. I actually did that one first and the single quotes were referring to the `caller`. I later changed my lingo for clarity but missed that one

Comment: Is there a way to find out the caller of the plugin?

Comment: All of the `this` keywords that I marked as "referencing the caller of the plugin" are the caller of the plugin. I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking? Plugins are called with the following syntax: `var $caller = $("someSelector"); $caller.somePlugin();`

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the object that this function is a method of

window <---- this (could be a button or textbox, etc.) ------- function()

in this case karl is correct, watermark.

Comment: He wanted to know specifically what each one referred to.